# Hibernate - Unable to execute command

Tags: java, hibernate, oracle10g

Hibernate throws an `Unable to execute command` exception. 
The relationship is like a `Customer` can have many `Credits`.

```
    INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Hibernate: 
    drop table Credits cascade constraints
Hibernate: 
    drop table Customer cascade constraints
Jun 03, 2016 3:58:30 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [
    drop table Customer cascade constraints]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [
    drop table Customer cascade constraints]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.Driver.main(Driver.java:15)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:942)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1770)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1739)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more

Hibernate: 
    drop sequence hibernate_sequence
Hibernate: create sequence hibernate_sequence start with 1 increment by 1
Hibernate: 
    create table Credits (
        bill_id number(10,0) not null,
        customer_id number(10,0) not null,
        liters number(10,0) not null,
        price number(10,0) not null,
        product varchar2(255 char),
        purchase_amount number(10,0) not null,
        primary key (bill_id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    create table Customer (
        customer_id number(10,0) not null,
        customer_name varchar2(255 char),
        date varchar2(255 char),
        primary key (customer_id)
    )
Hibernate: 
    alter table Credits 
        add constraint FKac2p66dfr7gaw7aumwj9ixs71 
        foreign key (CUSTOMER_ID) 
        references Customer
Jun 03, 2016 3:58:30 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [
    create table Customer (
        customer_id number(10,0) not null,
        customer_name varchar2(255 char),
        date varchar2(255 char),
        primary key (customer_id)
    )]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [
    create table Customer (
        customer_id number(10,0) not null,
        customer_name varchar2(255 char),
        date varchar2(255 char),
        primary key (customer_id)
    )]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:408)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.Driver.main(Driver.java:15)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:942)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1770)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1739)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more

Jun 03, 2016 3:58:30 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl handleException
WARN: GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Unable to execute command [
    alter table Credits 
        add constraint FKac2p66dfr7gaw7aumwj9ixs71 
        foreign key (CUSTOMER_ID) 
        references Customer]
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Unable to execute command [
    alter table Credits 
        add constraint FKac2p66dfr7gaw7aumwj9ixs71 
        foreign key (CUSTOMER_ID) 
        references Customer]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:408)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:458)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:708)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
    at com.Driver.main(Driver.java:15)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:183)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:942)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:1770)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:1739)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:51)
    ... 13 more

Jun 03, 2016 3:58:30 PM org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl applyImportSources
INFO: HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@bf4e60'
Hibernate: 
    select
        hibernate_sequence.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    select
        hibernate_sequence.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Customer
        (customer_name, date, customer_id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Jun 03, 2016 3:58:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1747, SQLState: 42000
Jun 03, 2016 3:58:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Jun 03, 2016 3:58:30 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl release
INFO: HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
Jun 03, 2016 3:58:30 PM org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$5 mapManagedFlushFailure
ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [could not execute statement]
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2921)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3421)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:560)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:434)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1295)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3135)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65)
    at com.Driver.main(Driver.java:36)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:91)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:206)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:455)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:413)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:1034)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:194)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:953)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1222)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3468)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
    ... 18 more
```

`Customer.java`

```
    package com;

import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    private int customer_id;
    private String customer_name;
    private String date;
    private List <Credits> credits;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }
    public void setCustomer_id(int customer_id) {
        this.customer_id = customer_id;
    }
    public String getCustomer_name() {
        return customer_name;
    }
    public void setCustomer_name(String customer_name) {
        this.customer_name = customer_name;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Credits.class, mappedBy="customer", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Credits> getCredits() {
        return credits;
    }
    public void setCredits(List<Credits> credits) {
        this.credits = credits;
    }

}
```

`Credits.java`

```
package com;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Credits {

    private int bill_id;
    private int customer_id;
    private int purchase_amount;
    private int price;
    private int liters;
    private String product;
    private Customer customer;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getBill_id() {
        return bill_id;
    }
    public void setBill_id(int bill_id) {
        this.bill_id = bill_id;
    }
    public int getCustomer_id() {
        return customer_id;
    }
    public void setCustomer_id(int cust_id) {
        this.customer_id = cust_id;
    }
    public int getPurchase_amount() {
        return purchase_amount;
    }
    public void setPurchase_amount(int purchase_amount) {
        this.purchase_amount = purchase_amount;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getLiters() {
        return liters;
    }
    public void setLiters(int liters) {
        this.liters = liters;
    }
    public String getProduct() {
        return product;
    }
    public void setProduct(String product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

}
```

`Driver.java`

```
    package com;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class);
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Credits.class);
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setCustomer_name("Rahul Shaw");
        customer.setDate("03-06-2016");
        session.save(customer);


        Credits credits = new Credits();
        credits.setLiters(15);
        credits.setPrice(10);
        credits.setProduct("OIL");
        credits.setPurchase_amount(500);
        credits.setCustomer(customer);

        //session.save(customer);
        session.save(credits);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

    }

}
```

`Helper.java`

```
    package com;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

   public class Helper {
        public static SessionFactory getSession() {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Customer.class);
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Credits.class);
            SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

            return sessionFactory;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I'd guess that `invalid identifier` is the root cause which indicates that the constraint name might be invalid or maybe there a case problem, i.e. `foreign key (CUSTOMER_ID)` references a non-existing column since the correct name would be `customer_id`.  Try `@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")` instead of `@JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")`.

Comment: Besides the comment above you'd normally not let Hibernate generate/update the database schema in production systems but rather do it manually (at least provide the statements in some way). That's not a solution for your problem although it might provide for a workaround, which is "drop hbm2ddl" entirely.

Comment: On using `@JoinColumn(name="customer_id")`, I get this - `Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.Credits column: customer_id`

Comment: The reason might be that you have `customer` and `customer_id` in `Credits` which is kind of redundant. I'd suggest removing `customer_id`.

Comment: But, `customer_id` has to be the foreign key!

Comment: You definitely need a _column_ for that but in Hibernate that is the _join column_ and not needed as a separate property. In your entity model you'll normally never see the join columns directly (except in the mapping).

Comment: So, what should be the work around here ?

Comment: As suggested by thomas,remove the "private int customer_id;" field from your credits.java class and try

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing dialect according to your version.

```
Oracle (any version)    org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect
Oracle9i                org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect
Oracle10g               org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

try or google search your version of dialect.